# TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

Tags: python

I'm working on a piece of code that polls for cricket score and gives a pop message in win machine. there is this waring that keeps coming after the pop up message is displayed. I'm not able to figure out what is causing this

WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT

TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

```
import requests 
import feedparser
import sys
from time import sleep
from win10toast import ToastNotifier



def user_input():
    team = str(input("enter team name: "))
    return team

def loadrss(team_name):
    xml_score = feedparser.parse("https://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml")
    for entry in xml_score.entries:
        if team_name not in entry.title:
            pass
        else:
            playing_team = entry.description
            return playing_team
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    user_in = user_input()
    get_rss = loadrss(user_in)
    if get_rss == None:
        result = ToastNotifier()
        result.show_toast("Cricket update", "Team "+user_in.upper()+" Not playing", icon_path= 'Cricket.ico', duration = 10,threaded=True)
        
    
    else: 
        while True:
            get_rss = loadrss(user_in)
            message = ToastNotifier()
            message.show_toast("Cricket update",get_rss, icon_path= 'Cricket.ico', duration = 10,threaded=True)
            
            sleep(30)
```

I tried to look in the documentation for ToastNotifier and the parameters I passed appear to be correct

It would be helpful if someone put me in correct direction
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing is correct; this is an [issue of win10toast](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/112) that happens on Windows 11. The warning does not influence the functionality, so you can ignore it. If it is a problem, though, you can try a different library (win10toast maybe?) or if your script is a part of a bigger application, you can try to suppress this warning.